# Switch between two scope variables in a view if one is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two scope variables: `$scope.banner`and `$scope.defaultBanner`.

I am getting the banner through a service, but if the banner's file does not exist my variable will be empty because my service will not return anything.

So I want it so if `$scope.banner`is undefined, then I show the `defaultBanner`instead. But of course the banner coming from the service must be shown priority.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I am actually looking for an angular trick or anything that could be place directly in my html view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this (awesome) tricks :

```
<img ng-src="{{banner || defaultBanner}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
.success(function(results){
    $scope.banner = results || $scope.defaultBanner;
})
```

Comment: Indeed this should work but for some reason inherent to my code, I can not change the content of the callback success function of my service.